# How to parse XML file via InDesign script

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, adobe-indesign

The title speaks for itself. I tried to look for a parser in JavaScript but they don't seem to work in InDesign. Does somebody know how to do it?

Comment: There's a parser included in InDesign, [see docs here](http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/pc_XML.html).

Comment: Another option is to import XML into structure and use XML Suite http://jongware.mit.edu/idcs6js/index_XML%20Suite.html

Answer (score 2):

```js
var xmlFile = File( "/some/xml/file/url" );
xmlFile.open("r");
var myXMLObject = XML ( xmlFile.read() );
xmlFile.close();
alert( myXMLObject.name() );
```